# Set child to have a percentage width of a parent

Tags: android, android-layout, android-layout-weight, android-percent-layout

There are 3 `LinearLayout` containers with `horizontal` orientation. The first two `LinearLayout` each have 4 `TextView` children. The third one has only 3. I have created and assigned style to all of the `TextView` children. Style fragment:

```
<item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
<item name="android:layout_weight">.25</item>
```

With this style first two rows are aligned nicely and each child `TextView` uses a quarter of parent's width. However `TextView` components in the third `LinearLayout` each use a third of parents width.

So components alignment is like this:

```
A1xxxx A2xxxx A3xxxx A4xxxx
B1xxxx B2xxxx B3xxxx B4xxxx
  C1xxxx  C2xxxx  C3xxxx
```

And not like this (as expected):

```
A1xxxx A2xxxx A3xxxx A4xxxx
B1xxxx B2xxxx B3xxxx B4xxxx
C1xxxx C2xxxx C3xxxx
```

**Solution:**
I have tried manually changing `android:layout_weight` property for each child in the third row and if I set `layout_weight` of `C1`, `C2` and `C3` to `0.25` `0.25` and `0.5` I get the desired alignment.

**Question:** I am doing something wrong since my initial solution to have each `TextView` have property `<item name="android:layout_weight">.25</item>` does not work as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong and the result that You are getting is expected.

You just need to add `android:weightSum` to 1 to the third LinearLayout. Because, by default the value of `android:weightSum` is set to the sum of children's `layout_weight`

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:text="xhajxnuwxnu"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:text="xhajxnuwxnu"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:text="xhajxnuwxnu"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:text="xhajxnuwxnu"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:text="xhajxnuwxnu"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:text="xhajxnuwxnu"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:text="xhajxnuwxnu"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:text="xhajxnuwxnu"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:text="xhajxnuwxnu"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:text="xhajxnuwxnu"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:text="xhajxnuwxnu"/>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Adding 4th child in the third row and setting property `android:layout_weight="5"` is both hacky and not intuitive. My question is exactly about that - why intuitive solution (`<item name="android:layout_weight">.25</item>`) does not work. I am not asking how to "do that" since with my (cleaner/less hacky) solution I have already achieved desired result.